# Send the Multimedia Message through SMS offline and convert it into bytes first

Tags: c#, uwp

How I can send multimedia (voice message, pics) through sim card SMS with C# in UWP?  *
if I *upload the pic then I can set its resolution to send it through SMS*.  
 Which ***API is supported in Windows*** for this purpose?  
 And how to convert the multimedia message into bytes.  
 Help me please

Answer (score 0):

> Which API is supported in Windows for this purpose

Unfortunately, for normal developer, it is impossible currently.

Part of underlying APIs are existing in [`Windows.Devices.Sms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sms) namespace, but most of functionalities are only available to mobile operator apps and Windows Store apps given privileged access by mobile network operators, mobile broadband adapter IHV, or OEM. For more information, see [Mobile Broadband: Windows Store device apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/hh852368.aspx).

For developing an alternative to the built-in messaging app, all APIs are under [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat) namespace, the MMS message is not supported currently

Please submit your feature request using the Feedback app, this is a good way to let MS know what users/developers need.